# Random array, generating lottery variable error

Tags: java, arrays

I have to generate 6 random numbers in an array less than or equal to 49- zeros are not allowed. Ask the user to enter any 6 numbers. I need my program to check if each number entered is equal to any random number generated. Display a message related to the number of correct guesses. And use a loop to allow the player to play again if they want.

I am done everyting but the play again. I dont know how to get the user to input yes or no.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class LuckyTask2{
public static void main(String args[]){

// TASK 2 
//boolean play = true;
//
//while(play == true){
//    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int lucky1,lucky2,lucky3,lucky4,lucky5,lucky6,number=0;
int j;
int Data[] = new int [6];
for(j=0; j<Data.length;++j){
Data[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 49);
//System.out.println(Data[j]);
int playagain=0;
}
do{

String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky1=Integer.parseInt(input2);

String input3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your second lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky2=Integer.parseInt(input3);

String input4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your third lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky3=Integer.parseInt(input4);

String input5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your fourth lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky4=Integer.parseInt(input5);

String input6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your fifth lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky5=Integer.parseInt(input6);

String input7 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your sixth lucky number between 1 and 49.");
lucky6=Integer.parseInt(input7);


for(j = 0; j< Data.length; j++){

if(Data[j]==lucky1){
number=number+1;
}
if(Data[j]==lucky2){
number=number+1;
}
if(Data[j]==lucky3){
number=number+1;
}
if(Data[j]==lucky4){
number=number+1;
}
if(Data[j]==lucky5){
number=number+1;
}
if(Data[j]==lucky6){
number=number+1;
} }

if(number==0){
System.out.println("Unfortunately, none of your numbers were winning numbers. Better luck next time!");
}
if(number==1){
System.out.println("One of your numbers was a  winning number. You win a free play!");
}
if(number==2){
System.out.println("Two of your numbers were winning numbers. You win $10");
}
if(number==3){
System.out.println("Three of your numbers were winning numbers. You win a share of 4.25% of Pools Fund");
}
if(number==4){
System.out.println("4 of your numbers were winning numbers. You win a share of 3.35% of Pools Fund");
}
if(number==5){
System.out.println("5  of your numbers were winning numbers.You win Share of 3.15% of Pools Fund");
}
if(number==6){
System.out.println("WOW! Congrats! All of your numbers were winning numbers. You win win or share Jackpot of at least $10 Million (89.25% of Pools Fund)");
}

//    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)");
//    String playagain = input.nextLine();
//    if (playagain == "Yes")
//       play = true;
//    else
//       play = false;

}}
```

Comment: i1 only exists in the scope of the for loop.

Comment: @Mathemats I declared i1 as an integer outside the loop now and Now it keeps asking the user input "Please enter a number between 1-49". After i enter six numbers i get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Answer (score 0):

`i1` scope/visibility is limited to your `for` loop and all of your `if` statements are outside for loop

Comment: I declared i1 as an integer outside the loop now and Now it keeps asking the user input "Please enter a number between 1-49". After i enter six numbers i get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Answer (score 0):

Its because you declared i1 inside of the for loop. Try declaring it outside of it; eg

```
int i1 = 0;
for(i1=0;...
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

```
for(i1 = 0; i1 < Data1.length; i1++){
    if(Data1[i1] = lucky1)
        same++;
    if(...
```

and continue this.

Comment: Now it keeps asking the user input "Please enter a number between 1-49". After i enter six numbers i get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Comment: I'm thinking its because when you are looking through the Data1 array, you are starting off with value 6, as that is what is returned from the for loop ( i1  ). Reset i1 to zero whilst making another for loop containing your block of if statements. Ive slightly edited my answer to show this

Comment: Thats okay :-) If you could up-vote that would be great, would help others with a similar issue. Also i'm one off being able to comment >:(